# Monitor network traffic on Android 7 and up

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to figure out a way to monitor network traffic on Android 7 and up. I used to use Charley proxy but it seems the new android OS needs an SSL certificate. Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get charles proxy work with Android 7 nougat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215229/how-to-get-charles-proxy-work-with-android-7-nougat)

Comment: or also https://stackoverflow.com/q/49954700/208273